# Cannot find OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb

Tags: proj

I'm running Proj 6.3.1

When running

```
projinfo -s epsg:27700 -t epsg:4326
```

Is see

```
Grid OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb needed but not found on the system. Can be obtained from the proj-datumgrid-europe package at https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-europe-1.5.zip
```

But when I download that and unzip this in this folder

```
/.local/share/proj
```

And run it again I still get the same warning.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would expect it to be in either /usr/local/... Or ~/.local/...

Comment: Is there some way to make proj print the data folder? I do not seem to have a /usr/local folder

Comment: You can check where it searches with `strace -e file projinfo -s epsg:27700 -t epsg:4326`

Comment: Check the environmental variable `PROJ_LIB`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look on my ubuntu machine and it looks like `/usr/share/proj/` is where you are looking for - if that's not it then `locate gsb` should find it.